# Template default to a template with more templates

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, c++-chrono

I am trying to create a function that has a template return type that's based on another template and I would like to default it as well. It's hard to explain it but here's the code:

```
template<template<typename ReturnType = float, typename> DurationType = std::chrono::duration<ReturnType, std::milli> >
ReturnType tick()
{
    high_resolution_clock::time_point currentPoint = high_resolution_clock::now();
    DurationType elapsed = currentPoint - mStartTimePoint;
    mStartTimePoint = currentPoint;

    return elapsed.count();
}
```

Obviously the above doesn't compile but what I'm trying to do is have the function return `ReturnType` (`float` or `double` likely) and also specify the unit of the return type. In this case, I want it default to milliseconds. Is this possible?

Comment: What you want to achieve here is not clear. Why promote `DurationType` to the function's template parameters when it doesn't even appear in it's interface? You can just have `ReturnType` as your only template param and replace `DurationType` with `auto`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't clear to me what, exactly, do you want express and what you want default.

You can, by example, define a template `ReturnT` type, with a default, and express a `DurationT` type with a default that depend from `ReturnT`; something like

```
template <typename ReturnT = float, 
          typename DurationT = std::chrono::duration<ReturnT, std::milli>>
ReturnT tick0 ()
 {
   std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point
      currentPoint { std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() };

   DurationT elapsed { currentPoint } ;

   return elapsed.count();
 }
```

But is acceptable that this function is called with a `DurationT` with a return type different than `ReturnT`?

I mean: is acceptable the following call ?

```
foo0<long double, std::chrono::duration<float, std::milli>>();
```

I suppose it isn't.

So I think you should express only one type and derive the other.

You can express the `DurationT`, with `std::chrono::duration<float, std::milli>` default, and deduce `ReturnT` from it; by example

```
template <typename DurationT = std::chrono::duration<float, std::milli>>
decltype( std::declval<DurationT>().count() ) tick1 ()
 {
   std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point
      currentPoint { std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() };

   DurationT elapsed { currentPoint } ;

   return elapsed.count();
 }
```

Or you can express the `ReturnT`, with default `float`, and deduce the `DurationT` from it; by example

```
template <typename ReturnT = float>
ReturnT tick2 ()
 {
   using DurationT = std::chrono::duration<ReturnT, std::milli>;

   std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point
      currentPoint { std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() };

   DurationT elapsed { currentPoint } ;

   return elapsed.count();
 }
```

Comment: I keep thinking I need to use template template ... because my template has another template in it.

Comment: @ChaoSXDemon - there are circumstances where is useful; but I don't think in this case.